Why is my authenticated-user route coming back not authenticated?
I am building an API in Laravel using tymon/jwt-auth and my authenticate-user route is returning not authenticated.
The login endpoint returns a successful response, so the issue is with authenticate_user(). I am not sure if i need to validate the cookie token differently than i am doing, but it is returning not authenticated when running the authenticate_user() method. Am I JWT properly?
AuthController.php
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
  
        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json([
                "message" => "Error logging in: Invalid credentials."
            ], 401);
        }

        // Set the JWT token in an HttpOnly cookie
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "Login successful!"
        ], 200)->cookie('authToken', $token, auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60, '/', null, true, true, false, 'Strict');
    }

    public function authenticate_user()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        if(!$user) {
            return response()->json([
                "message" => "User not authenticated."
            ], 401);
        }

        $roles = $user->getRoleNames();
        $permissions = $user->getAllPermissions();

        return response()->json([
            'isAuthenticated' => true,
            "user" => $user,
            'roles' => $roles,
            'permissions' => $permissions->pluck('name')
        ], 200);
    }

Routes in api.php
/**
 * Not Authenicated Routes
 */
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name("login");


/**
 * Authenicated routes
 */
Route::middleware('api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/authenticate-user', [AuthController::class, 'authenticate_user']);
});

When i run http://localhost:8000/api/authenticate-user, I get user is not authenticated.

If I'm understanding correctly, you are using this package:
https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quick-start/
Here, you can see the modifications to the User model, I can't see if you did that. Also did you configure auth.php to use the jwt driver for api guard?
